# How to combine two SQL delete statements into one

Tags: sql

How can these two delete statements be changed into one query/script?

```
DELETE FROM table1
WHERE Column1 IN ('value1');

DELETE FROM table2
WHERE column2 IN ('value2');
COMMIT COMMENT 'Deleting junk data';
```

Comment: a delete statement can only remove rows from one table at a time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They can't be made into a single delete statement, but they don't have to be; you can just execute them one after another within the scope of the same transaction, even as a single command string if you want these commands run from another program.

If you really want to do one thing that results in these statements being executed, create a stored procedure with this body (optionally specifying the criteria you're looking for as parameters) and execute that.